# angularfire & ui.sortable : passing ng-repeat value into sortableOptions

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-sortable

I have a basic ng-repeat where task is sortable

```
 <div ng-sortable="sortableOptions">
 <div ng-repeat="task in todo">
 {{task}}
 ...
```

when a task is draged and droped, it calls $scope.sortableOptions in my controller. I'm wondering if anyone knows how I could pass the task object into that? Could I set it up as a function or..

Basically, I want to pass the task in and update one of the properties inherent to todo.

```
$scope.sortableOptions2 = {
    stop: function(event, ui) {
     // do something with the specific todo here
    });

}
```

thank u

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [ng-sortable](http://ngmodules.org/modules/ng-sortable) Yeah you can do that ,

```
<ul data-as-sortable="sortableOptions" data-ng-model="todo">
   <li data-ng-repeat="item in todo" data-as-sortable-item>
      <div data-as-sortable-item-handle></div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

And in your controller ,

```
$scope.sortableOptions = {
    accept: function (sourceItemHandleScope, destSortableScope) {return boolean}//override to determine drag is allowed or not. default is true.
    itemMoved: function (event) {//Do what you want},
    orderChanged: function(event) {//Do what you want},
    containment: '#board'//optional param.
};
```

[See the documentation here](https://github.com/a5hik/ng-sortable)

Comment: maybe its an issue of my set up in general ... but on my angular page I have a ng-repeat = " todo in todos" , follwed later on by a ng-repeat = " task in todo.tasks".  The ng-data-model = "todo.tasks" does not seem to work properly and references the earlier sortable.  Any thoughts?